# Invoking class object method via scriptlet in servlet

Tags: java, servlets, scriptlet

I have a servlet and I want to run .java code through scriptlet. I have a simple class in Temp.java.

```
package pack;

import static java.lang.System.out;

public class Temp {

    public static void main()
    {out.println("trololo");

    }

}
```

And I want to invoke main method via scriptlet in index.jsp

```
<body>
    <%@ page import="pack.*" %>

    <%
    out.println("whatever");
    Temp temp = new Temp();
    temp.main();
    %>

</body>
```

What I have to do to make main function work after invoking via scriptlet? Printing "whatever" works, but main function doesn't print anything.

Comment: Where do you think that will print?

Comment: Bad idea.  This is not a good design.  Scriptlets are a sign that you're off base.

Comment: So please tell me what I should use? I am using scriptlet because I want to invoke .java code which invokes .groovy code. Groovy script is main thing I need to launch. And .groovy output doesn't need to be on servlet main page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will print on console, check logs

you imported

```
import java.lang.System.out;
```

which is standard output, so check your stdout log

Use [JSTL](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info) instead

Comment: Nothing was in main console, but in Glassfish output i could see result from main(). But "whatever" was printed in localhost:8080/WebApplication1/ so it was strange to me that the same code from main() is not also there. Thanks Jigar for the link. Greets.